# JNI without C++ source file

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I am working on a Android APP project with JNI. I have some source of the project, but i only have .so file and the .java file of the source. How can i use the JNI function without the C++ source file?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Java class that interfaces this **.so**, you don't need C++ sources to use it. You can even change the native methods from **protected** to **public**, if you need, or add in Java wrapper methods that can make using the native methods easier.

Speaking of Android, make sure that your **.so** file matches the platform (e.g. you cannot use an x86 library on ARM devices). Your **.so** must have been compiled with a compatible toolchain (e.g. you cannot use Linux compiler). And if your **.so** was built for certain platform, it may fail to load on older devices: NDK platforms are compatible forward, not backwards.

Comment: Thankyou for your help!
but the android studio require me the implement the JNI function.
what should i do??

Comment: You can disable this inspection by turning off Preferences > Inspections > Android > "Missing JNI function". But then, you must make sure that the native lib is prepared correctly.

Comment: "you must make sure that the native lib is prepared correctly."
I think this is my main problem

Comment: If you have specific questions about the native library, feel free to ask. More often than not, you can reverse engineer the names of native methods that are implemented. Sometimes, you can even reverse engineer the expected parameters of these methods.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What should I add to my code can let the JNI work ?? Is it about the Android.mk file problem or just include some library?

Comment: Android.mk won't help if you don't have access to C++ source files.

Comment: Before we can resolve your porblem, we will need to go through some diagnostic steps to determine what the problem actually is. I think that such one-on-one session does not match the format of Stack Overflow, it's better handled through an instant messenger.

Comment: How can i link the jni function in java with the .so file??

Comment: usually, linkage of native Java methods with their JNI implementations is done by exported function name